# Why Can't I train the ANN for XNOR?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have made a simple NN for deciding the XNOR values with the Two Binary values in the Input layer.
I have the Numpy array of all the possible combinations with the lables.

Code :

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

data = numpy.array([[0.,0.,1.],[0.,1.,0.],[1.,0.,0.],[1.,1.,1.]])
train = data[:,:-1] # Taking The same and All data for training
test = data[:,:-1]  

train_l = data[:,-1]
test_l = data[:,-1]

train_label = []
test_label = []

for i in train_l:
    train_label.append([i])
for i in test_l:
    test_label.append([i])   # Just made Labels Single element...

train_label = numpy.array(train_label)
test_label = numpy.array(test_label)  # Numpy Conversion


model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(2,input_dim = 2,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'relu'))

model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy" , metrics = ['accuracy'], optimizer = 'adam')

model.fit(train,train_label, epochs = 10, verbose=2)

model.predict_classes(test)
```

Even if taking the Same dataset to train and to test... It doesn't predict properly ...
Where was I wrong ?

I have taken whole dataset deliberately as it wasn't predicting with 2 values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your architecture is just too simple for this function. If you use the architecture below and train for 100 epochs, you'll get accuracy = 1.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20,input_dim = 2,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(20,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

**UPD:
Why a simple model doesn't work that well?**

One reason is that with a ReLU activation, if one neuron becomes negative on every data point, its gradient becomes zero, and its weights don't train any more. You have few neurons the start, and if some of them "die" this way, the remaining neurons may not be enough to approximate the function.

Another problem is that fewer neurons make it more likely for a model to get stuck in a local minimum.

However, you are right that theoretically, just a few neurons should be enough.
The model below works even with just one layer. I've replaced ReLU with LeakyReLU to remedy the first problem. It works most of the time, but sometimes gets stuck in a local minimum.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(2,input_dim = 2,activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)))
model.add(Dense(1,activation = 'sigmoid'))

optimizer = Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy" , metrics = ['accuracy'], optimizer=optimizer)

model.fit(train,train_label, epochs = 500, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Also changing last layer's activation from relu to sigmoid might be important for the currently used loss function.

Comment: Yes, sigmoid activation pairs well with binary crossentropy loss, that's why I chose it.

Comment: @seed That happened !! Can you tell me why that happened ? We we required 20 when we just need 2 as the nodes or the neurons ? Please Explain... And thanks for the architecture.